# Automatically redraw Plot once Locator has changed

Tags: graphics, dynamic

I have a `Dynamic` inside `LocatorPane` which provides a value to be used in several other places. The idea is to have a Plot that automatically updates once the Locator changes value. First, I define a point and a Locator control restricted to the unit disk:

```
pt = {1/2, 0};
LocatorPane[Dynamic[pt, (pt = #; pt = Function[{pnt}, If[Norm[pnt, 2] < 1, pnt, Normalize[pnt, 
(Norm[#, 2] &)]]] /@pt) &], Graphics[{LightGray, Disk[{0, 0}, 1]}, ImageSize -> 100]]
```

Next, I set up the plot to draw a horizontal line at the Locator's current y-value:

```
Plot[pt[[2]], {x, -5, 5}]
```

This works, but the plot is not auto-updated once the Locator changes position. Interestingly, `Dynamic[pt[[2]]]` works if used standalone but not inside the plot. How can I make this work?

---

**Edit:**
As suggested in the comments, enclosing the plot in `Dynamic` does the trick.

There is a similar issue where that does not work, apparently:

```
ContourPlot[{[f[1, C1, C2] == 0, g[2, C1, C2] == Pi/2}, {C1, -6, 6}, {C2, -6, 6}]
```

with `f[x,C1,C2]`, `g[x,C1,C2]` being dependent on (dynamic) x and the real parameters $C1$, $C2$. These functions will intersect depending on $C1$, $C2$, so I tried to wrap `ContourPlot` inside `Dynamic`, and also each function separately. Why is `ContourPlot` evading my efforts?

Comment: tried `Dynamic[Plot[pt[[2]], {x, -5, 5}]]`?

Comment: @kglr: That was it. There is a `ContourPlot` where that does not work, though.